# Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection profile "defaultProfile"

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Using Mac OS 10.12

https://github.com/fabric-composer/sample-applications with commit c5aa100d2532b7ec085a650e515a677dc3446ad2

when I run `npm test` in getting-started directory, I got below error

error: [Composer-GettingStarted] Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection profile "defaultProfile"
Command failed.

Answer (score 1):

Received answer from fabric-composer channel in Rocket chat. Here's the solution to fix it provided by Dan

this is usually an install issue. Try running `npm uninstall -g composer-cli` followed by `npm install -g composer-cli` and check that there are no install issues. Also delete the `node_modules` folder from getting started and then rerun `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

```
sudo npm uninstall -g composer-rest-server && sudo npm install -g composer-rest-server
```

Answer (score 0):

[When I run ./createPeerAdminCard.sh](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools#starting-and-stopping-hyperledger-fabric), I got the same error message.

> Try running npm uninstall -g composer-cli followed by npm install -g composer-cli

It's resolved the above work around.

My environment is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ npm ls -g composer-cli
/usr/lib
└── composer-cli@0.16.6
$ composer-rest-server -v
v0.16.6
$ composer-playground --version
0.16.6
```